# No response from swift post request

Tags: swift, curl, post, urlsession

Need to do a post request in order to complete oauth2.0 authentication.

It works fine in curl:

```
curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'clientId=cgoxyBxM1KVO3pLm5J7VgDVxlP7_33BpPlPXeIaSmoLsTZq8DfyM1svTwi-SU7KJKBRN4V3mIsV7pNNEg610Xw' https://fmsauth.scania.com/auth/S2S4DA/ClientId2Challenge
```

I get this kind of response:

```
{"challenge":"_jEEFcI36cvfMac8BHG8R0iIp4g7I-t0-C9LKAjwl9Y"}
```

I try the same thing in swift, but I get zero response back:

```
import Foundation

let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://fmsauth.scania.com/auth/S2S4DA/ClientId2Challenge")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let payload = Data("clientId=cgoxyBxM1KVO3pLm5J7VgDVxlP7_33BpPlPXeIaSmoLsTZq8DfyM1svTwi-SU7KJKBRN4V3mIsV7pNNEg610Xw".utf8)

let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: payload) { data, response, error in

    if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(dataString)
    }

    if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

I think there might be an issue with the payload data string. I don't know how the http post request 'data format' looks like in curl and swift.

Comment: Have you added breakpoints or checked for an error? Another thing you can do is use Postman to test your APIs.

Comment: I have just double checked and there are no breakpoints and no warnings or errors. The script runs and displays "Program ended with exit code: 0". I will check out postman, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 1**

Okay, after reading your comment, heres whats going on, the program is ending before your code is even being executed. A simple way to see this is if you add a break point in your code.

You can use a semaphore to block the current thread and wait for your URL session to finish.

> *A dispatch semaphore is an efficient implementation of a traditional
>   counting semaphore. Dispatch semaphores call down to the kernel only
>   when the calling thread needs to be blocked. If the calling semaphore
>   does not need to block, no kernel call is made.* [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsemaphore)

This code will do what you want it to.

```
var sema = DispatchSemaphore( value: 0 )
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: "https://fmsauth.scania.com/auth/S2S4DA/ClientId2Challenge")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
let payload = Data("clientId=cgoxyBxM1KVO3pLm5J7VgDVxlP7_33BpPlPXeIaSmoLsTZq8DfyM1svTwi-SU7KJKBRN4V3mIsV7pNNEg610Xw".utf8)

    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, from: payload) { data, response, error in

        if let data = data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(dataString)
             sema.signal()
        }

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print(httpResponse.statusCode)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    sema.wait()
```

**First post**

Your code works, I think you need to enable the transport. Add this to info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>somethingthatshouldntworkyourdomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Response

```
Code 200

{"challenge":"eeABaKaf2ZdhPEVQ4ru2S58_j37VLetM3pryIP8uiXk"}
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600003be73e0> { URL: https://fmsauth.scania.com/auth/S2S4DA/ClientId2Challenge } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Length" =     (
        182
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Wed, 15 Jan 2020 21:12:31 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        "Microsoft-IIS/8.5"
    );
    "Set-Cookie" =     (
        "BIGipServerfmsauth.scania.com_https_pool=!c+BZzlVtgeV0E7NCFLoANbUAp39TaIJT2kJgIPLs8cCAJ4R4UMhNbWVOiSnTd/Cx6OuLMGUfIpke3g==; path=/; Httponly; Secure"
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    "X-HandlingWebServer" =     (
        sesofms9112
    );
    "X-Powered-By" =     (
        "ASP.NET"
    );
    "owin.RequestId" =     (
        "4dbeb043-0e55-4972-b955-45c28f94aa77"
    );
} }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just used a Mac command line tool project, so I don't have a plist file but I should be able to add it :)

Comment: By the way, I just wanted to add that it is working in a iOS project even without changes to plist file. It still does not work in the command line tool project even with the added plist file but maybe I am doing something wrong. Anyway I can work with this, I just wanted to add the information for everyone else.